# How to display message when filtering records not found in Angular4

Tags: angular

I am implementing search functionality using amgular4 but i dont know how to display message when filtering records not found  in Angular4. 
Here i have two files template and component.

Search result template

```js
<ng-template #content>
  <div *ngIf="car">
            <div class="abc">Car Information</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card__body">
                      <p class="u-text-bold">Car number</p>
                    </div>
                  <div class="col">
                      <p class="u-text-bold">Car Color</p>
                    </div>
                      <p class="u-text-normal">{{Car.number}}</p>
                    </div>
                  <div class="col">

                      <p class="u-text-normal">{{Car.Color}}</p>

                  </div>

</ng-template>
```

Comment: Please share your service and result component

Comment: @ArunRedhu I have pasted my service code in comment. Do you need more input?

Comment: you can apply conditions using `*ngIf` and can use `else` block when data is not present or you can also use searchdata fetching in before router changes and then back to search component if data is not present

Comment: @ArunRedhu Where can i add the *ngif

Comment: The template in which you are showing your search results

Comment: @ArunRedhu I have updated my search result template. I have confusion with that where i will display the message here. Can you please update my code with your answer if possible. Basically a message should be displayed when the search returns an empty result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add condition in the view:

```
<div *ngIf="records?.length == 0;else data"> 
   ...
</div>
<ng-template #data>
  ...
</ng-template>
```

EDIT: This should be your view, if you have a list of cars:

```
<div *ngIf="cars?.length == 0;else data">
 <div *ngFor="let Car of cars;">
  <div class="abc">Car Information</div>
  <div class="card__body">
    <p class="u-text-bold">Car number</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p class="u-text-bold">Car Color</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="u-text-normal">{{Car.number}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p class="u-text-normal">{{Car.Color}}</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<ng-template #data>
   <h1>No records found</h1>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Why ? where are your data and your view ?

Comment: I have updated my search result template. I have confusion with that where i will display the message here. Can you please update my code with your answer if possible. Basically a message should be displayed when the search returns an empty result

Comment: What does your search return ? a car ?

Comment: is'nt is possible to add into component instead of template file.

Answer (score 0):

I might be thinking you are searching for `car` and if it is available then show the `car details` and if not then show the message. If this is the case then you can follow the following:

```
<div *ngIf="car; else noInfo>
    <div class="abc">Car Information</div>
    <div class="card__body">
      <p class="u-text-bold">Car number</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="u-text-bold">Car Color</p>
    </div>
    <p class="u-text-normal">{{Car.number}}</p>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="u-text-normal">{{Car.Color}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<ng-template #noInfo>Your message</ng-template>
```

For more on `if-else` in `Angular 4` You can visit this: https://medium.com/aviabird/ngif-else-lands-in-angular-2-0-a242940e54ff